# how recognize token ~ on flex?

Tags: c++, token, flex-lexer

I want to recognize token `~` on my language "simplex" and i'm using flex & bison with C++ and in the list of tokens I declare:

```
\~                        { return DISTRIBUTION; }
```

But when I try to program the input supports `~ =, ~!` and any token that is not in use after.

I guess the character `~` is simply ignored and I have to use a better regular expression handling or use expressions of bits.

Somebody can help my with this?

Comment: Have you tried to use the octal value like so: **'\176'** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"~"                        { return DISTRIBUTION; }
```

or

```
[~]                        { return DISTRIBUTION; }
```

Important:

first defined rule for(*if you have)* `~=` and `~!` then defined rule for `~`.

Comment: have you tried like this `[~] { return DISTRIBUTION; }`..Although this should work

Comment: Grijesh Chauhan can i send you by e-mail my proyect and you review?

Comment: @user1460053 : its 10:00 PM in India and I am in office but at-least I can check manually ...send if you wants

Comment: ok, where i can find your e-mail? mine it's tonylattke@gmail.com